# rpm installing an icon to the desktop

Tags: linux, gnome, fedora, rpm, rpmbuild

In Fedora Gnome...

Using a .desktop file in my rpm, I have successfully put my gui software into the gnome application menu.

I am wondering if there is a way to also put the icon onto the gnome desktop when installing the rpm?

**update:**

Now I can get `rpmbuild` to successfully use rpmbuild with `xdg-desktop-icon` in `%install`... and in the process puts an icon on my desktop (*before even installing the rpm!*)  I am doing something wrong.  Any suggestions?

Here is the relevant part of my spec file:

```
Source1: %{name}.desktop
BuildRoot: %{_tmppath}/%{name}-%{version}-%{release}-root-%(%{__id_u} -n)
BuildRequires:  gettext, python-devel, desktop-file-utils, xdg-utils

...

%install
rm -rf $RPM_BUILD_ROOT
%{__python} setup.py install -O1 --skip-build --root $RPM_BUILD_ROOT
desktop-file-install --dir=${RPM_BUILD_ROOT}%{_datadir}/applications %{SOURCE1}
xdg-desktop-icon install --novendor %{SOURCE1}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Linux desktop shortcut and icon from install](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/73930/linux-desktop-shortcut-and-icon-from-install)

Comment: @Nathan Campos -- the answers to that question did not tell how to put an icon onto the desktop.  The comment from Colin on that page suggests it is not common practice, but doesn't tell how to do it.

Comment: just because the answers are wrong doesn't mean the question isn't a duplicate. You can bump the question to try to get more people to answer it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This thread will help anyone who comes here looking for more information:
http://lists.fedoraproject.org/pipermail/packaging/2011-February/007602.html

Comment: You linked to some mailing list email which provides a dead link. This is why SO answers aren't supposed to be just links to some other page on the internet. You need to actually provide an answer here.

Answer (score 1):

The page you linked to explains how to use `desktop-file-install` on the `%install` section of your `SPECS`. Apart from that, you may need to use `xdg-desktop-icon` from the `xdg-utils` package.

## EDIT:

Apparently, `%install` is to only be used at build time (at `make install` time). For package installation and removal there's `%pre`, `%post`, `%preun` and `%postun`. It looks like you should use `%post`, checking `$1` as explained on [https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Packaging:ScriptletSnippets](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Packaging%3aScriptletSnippets).

Comment: Thx!  xdg-desktop-icon seems like the right idea... I am having trouble using it correctly.  I've modified the o.p.  Any suggestions?